# AttributeError: module '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' has no attribute 'TFE_DEVICE_PLACEMENT_EXPLICIT_swigconstant'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Python 3.5 64 bit, Cuda 9.2, TensorFlow 1.11, Keras 2.2.4

I'm getting this error:

> AttributeError: module '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' has no attribute 'TFE_DEVICE_PLACEMENT_EXPLICIT_swigconstant'

Uninstalling and reinstalling TensorFlow stopped the message for `import tensorflow`, but the problem persists for `import keras`.

I have seen that `dumpbin.exe` has been useful for some people, but I've been unable to get it to work.

The problems started this morning while trying to get Tensor Board to work. I was updating python modules with pip and I'm not sure what set it off.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49218685/5072351). Follow the steps to resolve this issue. You can also refer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5747) to see the solution.